# TrueCaseAnnotator overwriteText option

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm attempting to write a sentiment predictor for reviews. The Stanford docs say that poorly written inputs, e.g. capitalization, can throw off their tools, like sentiment detection. This is the hole I'm in right now.

I have the following:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty( "annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, truecase, pos, parse, sentiment" );
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP( prop );
Annotation doc = new Annotation( "I LOVE Target products. I love myself, too." );
List<CoreMap> sentences = doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
for(CoreMap sentence : sentences)
{
  for(CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)
  {
    System.out.println(token + ": " + token.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class));
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

This outputs:

```
I-1: Neutral
LOVE-2: Neutral
Target-3: Neutral
products-4: Neutral
.-5: Neutral

I-1: Neutral
love-2: Very positive
myself-3: Neutral
,-4: Neutral
too-5: Neutral
.-6: Neutral
```

If the "LOVE" in the first sentence is `truecase`-d as "love", the sentiment comes out as "Very positive". From any perspective, "LOVE" should also be very positive. As this is tripping up sentiment detection, I wanted to apply `truecase-ing` in the pipeline before sentiment detection, the docs [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/truecase.html) mention the `truecase.overwriteText` configuration for the `TrueCaseAnnotator`, but that appears to only be for the commandline.

Questions:

1. How do I configure the `truecase`-ing stage in the pipeline to carry out the `overwriteText` step programmatically, via the API?
2. Generally, how does one configure Annotators in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the packaged properties files and the docs, I took a shot in the dark and did:

`prop.setProperty("truecase.overwriteText", "true");`

And that worked! This is the way to configure annotators in the pipeline.